# Flutter text overflow at beginning of sentence

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, ellipsis

I need to have overflow property of a text at the beginning of the sentence, so instead of

```
A very looooooooooong senten...
```

I want the result of the ellipsis to be

```
...ery looooooooooong sentence.
```

Can  this be set somehow?

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45336), there currently isn't a way to do this with the Material Text Widget's overflow property.

However you can use the `ExtendedText()` Widget from [extended_text](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text) package.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ExtendedText(
          'A very looooooooooong sentence.',
          maxLines: 1,
          overflowWidget: TextOverflowWidget(
            position: TextOverflowPosition.start,
            child: Text(
              "...",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
            ),
          ),
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 27),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: best answer i have