# I want text to overflow on left side

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, text-align

instead of (this is...)
but (...this is)

#I have write some seem cannot find a way

```
Widget name ({required String firstName,required String lastName}) {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: Text(firstName + " "+ lastName,
      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),),
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter text overflow at beginning of sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71502532/flutter-text-overflow-at-beginning-of-sentence)

Comment: What happens if you charge the text Direction to rtl